# Generate pixel/rem/percent sizes from a div class with a Sass mixin?

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins, dart-sass

Is there a way to generate pixel/percent/rem sizes with a sass mixin from a div class? For instance, here's an example of what the class might be set to:

```html
<div class="height-134px width-33percent">
```

And this would be the CSS output:

```css
.height-134px {
  height: 134px;
}

.width-33percent {
  width: 33%;
}
```

Basically trying to make it really easy for a content manager/designer to finely adjust certain things if needed.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not how Sass works. Sass doesn't read classes from your HTML. You'd have to first use Sass to create a class for every possible property and value for that to work. I'd suggest looking into CSS utility class frameworks like [Tachyons](https://tachyons.io/) or [Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/), which have predefined classes for a lot of things that content managers can then use in HTML.